# Dropzone.js "Undefined index: file" How to use with Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5, dropzone.js

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/), based on [Laravel](https://laravel.com/).

I have a working HTML form for uploading files.

```
<form class="dropzone" method="POST" action="/upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="hidden" name="_handler" value="onUpload" />

    <div class="fallback">
        <input type="file" name="file">
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

</form>
```

#### Dropzone

I'm trying to add [Dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com) to it. It says you just add the class to the form.

From Dropzone docs:
http://www.dropzonejs.com/#usage

*The uploaded files can be handled just as if there would have been a html input like this:*

```
<input type="file" name="file" />
```

That's what my form type and name already was before adding Dropzone.

#### Error

But when it gets to this line in my upload.php, I get an error:

```
$inputName = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
$inputExtension = pathinfo($inputName, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

`Error: Undefined index: file`

But it worked before without Dropzone, using the same name 'file'.

#### Laravel

It will pass without error if using:

```
$inputName = Input::file('file');
```

But now I have difficulty getting the file extention, because it's no longer in the variable using Input::file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do in your controller

```
$inputExtension = request('file')->extension();
$path = request('file')->path();
$file = $request->file('file');
```

**Update**

Please pass the request to your controller and rename your input to avoid confustion with Laravel 'file'.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $file = $request->file('image');
    $extension = $request->image->extension(); //or
    $originalExtension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();

    $path = $request->image->path();
}
```

**How october CMS does it**

```
$extension = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalExtension();
$name = Input::file('file')->getClientOriginalName();
```

So the key was to use getClientOriginalExtension();

Comment: I get "Call to a member function extension() on null". Maybe Input::file() isn't actually working?

Comment: Check my updates. I hope this works. Please rename your input to 'name', just to avoid cconfusion with Laravel `file` function.

Comment: I'm not knowledgeable enough with laravel to know where to put this or use the controller. In OctoberCMS I have my uploader in a custom Component.

Comment: I think it would still work. The function that handles your file upload, just pass `Request $request` as a parameter and do the rest inside of the function. I think it should work, though Im not familiar with October CMS

Comment: I put onUpload(Request $request) and in the function $inputExtension = $request->file->extension();

"Type error: Argument 1 passed to onUpload() must be an instance of MyVendor\Gallery\Components\Request, none given."

Comment: To change the 'file' to something else, I would have to refactor a lot of code and figure out how to change Dropzone to do it.

Comment: I also tried $inputExtension = \Request::file('file')->extension(); It returned "Call to a member function extension() on null".

Comment: ok check my update, I found out how October CMS does it. No need to pass request anymore. Just the way you were doing it already at the begining, only with a different function.

Comment: I was able to get getClientOriginalExtension() to work for the normal form, but it doesn't work with Dropzone, it returned "Call to a member function getClientOriginalExtension() on null".

Comment: The simple form uploader I've made works for normal uploads, but I was trying to use Dropzone for its drop feature and progress bar.